# FunctionalInterface is not an annotation type. Am using java 8 & eclipse oxygen

Tags: java, eclipse, java-8, annotations, eclipse-oxygen

I am quite new to using java 8 & haven't really used annotations before. When I try to write a simple program for functional interface using eclipse oxygen, java 8 & specify annotation @FunctionalInterface, I see the red x (error) saying FunctionalInterface is not an annotation type.

Please help to resolve this. I understand that giving an annotation is not mandatory, also my program runs fine without it, but still I want to use it.

Comment: Javadoc says "However, the compiler will treat any interface meeting the definition of a functional interface as a functional interface regardless of whether or not a FunctionalInterface annotation is present on the interface declaration." So it definitely not mandatory.

Comment: Have you perhaps defined a class called `FunctionalInterface`? Show us a [mcve]

Comment: Please share the code .

Comment: @talex The OP already said "I understand that giving an annotation is not mandatory"

Comment: You really need to show your code. As it stands this question is not useful, and resolving it is impossible.

Answer (score 5):

Hope you have not written your Interface as,

```
package com.practice;

@FunctionalInterface
public interface FunctionalInterface {
    void method1();
}
```

i.e the name of annotation and Interface is same.
The same thing which is mentioned by @greg-449 in you comment section.

Answer (score 1):

Please make sure if your Installed is pointing to jre 1.8 in eclipse
to verify you can go to Window> Preferences >java> installed Jre
if not then update it

Answer (score 0):

You should have Java 8 installed and your Eclipse should use Java 8, however, with Java 8, I saw the same issue. It went away after I imported it manually:

```
import java.lang.FunctionalInterface;
```

Then I decided to just do a clean build and the problem went away even "without" the import statement.

Answer (score 0):

Clean your project at first and even if that doesn't fix your problem, try to close the project and open the project again.

Answer (score 0):

Faced same issue as the name of interface was FunctionalInterface. Referring to earlier comments, updated the interface name and the annotation worked for me. No additional import is needed for @FunctionalInterface.

Answer (score 0):

If you defined the class name as FunctionalInterface then no need to use **@FunctionalInterface** annotation.
*Rename the class Name and try it out.*